# Django: failed: Error during WebSocket handshake

Tags: django, nginx, websocket, uwsgi, supervisord

I'm getting below error

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost/ws/testNoti?subscribe-broadcast&publish-broadcast&echo' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500
>
> Websocket connection is broken!

supervisor conf file

```
[unix_http_server]
username = ubuntu
password = password

[program:uwsgi]
command=/home/ubuntu/bxd-life/venv/bin/uwsgi --ini /home/ubuntu/bxd-life/bxd/bxd.ini
autostart=true
user=ubuntu
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile = /home/ubuntu/bxd-life/logs/err.log
stdout_logfile = /home/ubuntu/bxd-life/logs/out.log
stopsignal=INT

[program:uwsgi_ws]
command = /home/ubuntu/bxd-life/venv/bin/uwsgi --http :8080 --gevent 1000 --http-websockets --workers=2 --master --module bxd.wsgi_websockets
#directory=/home/ubuntu/bxd-life/bxd
autostart=true
autorestart=true
starttries=5
user=ubuntu
environment=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='bxd.settings'
```

nginx conf file

```
upstream app_server {
            server localhost:8000;
    }
upstream web_socket_server {
    server localhost:8080 fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    location /static/ {
        alias /home/ubuntu/bxd-life/bxd/static/;
        expires 30d;
    }

    location /ws/ {
            proxy_pass http://web_socket_server;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            #proxy_redirect ws://$server_name;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location / {
            try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }
    location @proxy_to_app {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass   http://app_server;
    }
  }
 }
```

wsgi_websockets.py

```
 import os
 import gevent.socket
 import redis.connection

 redis.connection.socket = gevent.socket
 os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "bxd.settings")
 from ws4redis.uwsgi_runserver import uWSGIWebsocketServer
 application = uWSGIWebsocketServer()
```

The above is working fine with `./manage.py runserver` but not with nginx!

Any help would be very much appreciated.